# convert a boolean jtable column to checkbox

Tags: sql, swing, jtable

i have written a program that reads the data from a database and the last column is boolean that 0 for false and 1 for true but i want to show that column as checkboxes . i will paste my code right now:
private void update_table(){

```
    String sql = "select dailies.id as 'م', customers.name as' العميل',ddate as' التاريخ' ,cars.name as' السيارة',material.name as' المادة',quantity as'عدد',dailytypes.name as' الوحدة',unitprice as' سعر الوحدة',discount as' الخصم',(unitprice*quantity - discount) as' الإجمالي',notes as' ملاحظات', paid as'تم السداد' from dailies,customers,cars,material,dailytypes where ddate=? and dailies.customer = customers.id and dailies.car = cars.id and dailies.material = material.id and dailies.type = dailytypes.id  order by ddate";
    try{
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, currentdate());
        pst.setString(1, currentdate());
        rs = pst.executeQuery();
        tbldailies.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
        //tbldailies.addColumn();
    }catch (Exception ex){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
    } finally{
        try{

            rs.close();
            rs1.close();
            pst.close();

        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: What have you tried already? Please read the following: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Answer (score 0):

"How to use Tables", from the Java tutorial, contains many examples of this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html

Answer (score 0):

At the [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) pointed to by @Keith:

```
public class NewbieTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
     // ...
     public Class getColumnClass(int c) {
           return getValueAt(0, c).getClass();
     }
     // ...
}
```

Hope that helps...